# `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt` vs frozen module versions

Tags: python, pip

How are module versions resolved when both specifying specific module version numbers in the `requirements.txt` file **and** passing the `--upgrade` option to pip install?

Example of specifying the module version number in the requirements.txt file:

```
numpy==1.18.1
```

Example of specifying the the --upgrade flag:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

Is there a best practice for avoiding this ambiguity when making releases (e.g. Docker images)?

Comment: Did you try it in practice? What was the outcome?

Comment: @phd: I have not tried it in practice. I am looking for a best practice; not just the specifics of the experiment. In practice, I suspect the specified version would not be overwritten; despite the --upgrade flag. That begs the question, is the --upgrade flag useful when using specific module versions.

Comment: "*I am looking for a best practice; not just the specifics of the experiment.*" Best practice questions are discouraged as they are [chatty, open-ended questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). "*In practice, I suspect the specified version would not be overwritten; despite the --upgrade flag.*" Yep, exactly. `--upgrade` is simply ignored. "*That begs the question, is the --upgrade flag useful when using specific module versions.*" No, not at all. It's useful to upgrade to the latest version but not to a specific version.

Comment: Thanks, @phd. I appreciate the answer. If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pip install --upgrade`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-U) is used to upgrade to the latest available version. When a particular version is specified `--upgrade` is ignored and could be omitted.